# Dropdown menu code not quite right on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have built a menu on this page that is live: https://boys-cry.com/ and it was working fine until I added the mobile background content on a different section and duplicated the below code and one instance is now hidden from the desktop and the other is hidden from the mobile view so that the correct background content appears on each device. But it seems to have stopped the menu functions working properly.

On the desktop, when you click the logo the menu shows, but the We and Client items in the dropdown do not expand when clicked - they are meant to show further text.

On the mobile when you click the logo nothing happens and its meant to show the menu and then subsequent text dropdowns.

Im sure I'm missing a small bit of code but cant see what it is. Please help! Thank you

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      let active = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-div .accordion.active");
      for (let j = 0; j < active.length; j++) {
        active[j].classList.remove("active");
        active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #00000000;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  max-width: 180px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #00000000;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  max-width: 180px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.accordion:focus {
  background-color: #00000000;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  max-width: 180px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.panel {
  color: black;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-out;
  background-color: #00000000;
  max-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: -4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 11px;
}

.link {
  background-color: #00000000;
  color: black;
  max-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: -4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 5px;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #00000000;
  color: black;
  max-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: -4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 0px 6px 5px;
}

hr.solid {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: none;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: #00000000;
  padding: 40px 12px 50px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://boys-cry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/bc_logo_black.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  animation-direction: pulse;
  animation-name: logo;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: #00000000;
  padding: 40px 12px 50px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://boys-cry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/bc_logo_black.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  animation-direction: pulse;
  animation-name: logo;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.dropbtn:focus {
  color: #00000000;
  padding: 40px 12px 50px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(https://boys-cry.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/bc_logo_black.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  outline: none;
  animation-direction: pulse;
  animation-name: logo;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes logo {
  from {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
}

#myDropdown>div {
  display: none
}

#myDropdown.show>div {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown">

      <div>
        <hr class="solid">
        <div class="accordion-div">
          <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">We</span></button>
          <div class="panel">
            <p style="padding:18px 0;">We are Content Creators.<br>We cultivate desire and change through story telling.</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="solid">
          <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading">Clients</span></button>
          <div class="panel">
            <p style="padding:18px 0;">Red Bull . Nike . Andrew Cotton . Dynamo . Coca Cola . Nowness . Selfridges . Levis . Liverpool FC . England Rugby . Rimowa . GQ</p>
          </div>
          <hr class="solid">
          <button class="accordion"><span class="faq__question-heading"><a class="link" href="mailto:info@boys-cry.com">Get In Touch</a></span></button>
          <div class="panel"></div>
        </div>
        <hr class="solid">
      </div>
```

Comment: I added a runnable snippet to your post. Aside from missing some closing tags in your HTML I'm not seeing an issue with the code you provided but you're right it's not working on your live site. Maybe compare the two and see where the differences are? https://jsfiddle.net/astombaugh/k6zvg5nL/7/

Comment: Sorry I cant actually see the bits you added? please could you paste those extras here? Although if the code is correct but not working on live site, something must be wrong. Does it have anything to do with having the same code on 2 screen sizes? Could you add something that says only use this code on a screen size of min-X?

Comment: Sorry, I added a snippet so other people could run your code on SO but it hasn't been approved by a mod yet :) The jsfiddle I linked is just your code which as far as I can tell works. For your dropdown button on mobile you might need to look into a touch event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events For targeting specific viewport sizes, you can use @media: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media But yeah, something's definitely interfering with your live site version. Try using your browser inspector to see what's happening as you try to use the nav.